# c++ counting +ve, -ve and zeros from user's input

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, void, do-while

I wanted to create a program that ask the user to input numbers. then the software will count how many positive, negative and zero numbers.

Note that I must use calling function.

This what I have done so far but still doesn't work properly

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void counting(double, double);

int main()
{
    float count, P=0, i;
    cout<< "how many numbers you wanna enter?" << endl;
    cin >> count;
    do {

        cout << "enter your number: " << endl;
        cin >> i;

        counting(count, i);

        P++;
    }
    while (P<count);

    return 0;     
}

void counting(double count, double i)
{
    int positive_Count = 0;
    int negative_Count = 0;
    int zero_Count     = 0;
    int u;

    for (u=0; u <= count; u++)
    {
       if (i > 0)
       {
          positive_Count++;
       }
       else if (i < 0)
       {
          negative_Count++;
       }
       else if (i == 0)
       {
          zero_Count++;
       }  
    }

    cout  << "Count of positive elements = " << positive_Count << endl
      << "Count of negative elements = " << negative_Count << endl
      << "Count of zero     elements = " << zero_Count << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's a pretty fundamental flaw in your logic. I would suggest you try debugging this, or even inserting some output statements to trace what its actually doing. Once you do that, your problem will be blindingly obvious.

Comment: _doesn't work properly ..._ is to vague for a question here. Please debug your program first, and ask a question about some particular behavior you don't understand, or that can't be explained from the c++ standard references.

Comment: why is `count` a floating-point variable? Are users allowed to enter 2.6 numbers?

Comment: I would start again with this code. It has too many flaws to recover from

Answer (score 0):

This is seriously flawed code. 
Suggestions -

- Read all the numbers first and copy them to a `dynamically allocated array`
- Pass that array to `counting function`
- Iterate over that array in the function in a `loop` and find the count of positive, negative numbers & zero

Comment: Rather than a dynamically allocated array, use `std::vector`.